# ImportError using Flask with wsgi and Apache2

Tags: python, apache, apache2, flask, wsgi

I'm trying to set up a simple website using Flask, wsgi, and apache2.  I'm getting the following error trying to import from site.py into site.wsgi:

```
[Fri Jan 11 16:42:20 2013] [error] [client 174.48.34.188] mod_wsgi (pid=15170): Target WSGI script '/home/www/site/site.wsgi' cannot be loaded as Python module.
[Fri Jan 11 16:42:20 2013] [error] [client 174.48.34.188] mod_wsgi (pid=15170): Exception occurred processing WSGI script '/home/www/site/site.wsgi'.
[Fri Jan 11 16:42:20 2013] [error] [client 174.48.34.188] Traceback (most recent call last):
[Fri Jan 11 16:42:20 2013] [error] [client 174.48.34.188]   File "/home/www/site/site.wsgi", line 1, in <module>
[Fri Jan 11 16:42:20 2013] [error] [client 174.48.34.188]     from site import app as application
[Fri Jan 11 16:42:20 2013] [error] [client 174.48.34.188] ImportError: cannot import name app
```

Here is my site.py:

```
from flask import Flask, render_template

app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/')
def home_page():
    return render_template('index.html')

app.debug = True
if __name__ == '__main__'
    app.run()
```

Here is my site.wsgi:

```
from site import app as application
```

And here is my apache config:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerAdmin my@email.here
    ServerName mywebsite.here
    DocumentRoot /home/www/site

    WSGIDaemonProcess site user=${APACHE_RUN_USER} group=${APACHE_RUN_GROUP} threads=5
    WSGIScriptAlias / /home/www/site/site.wsgi

    <Directory /home/www/site>
        WSGIProcessGroup site
        WSGIApplicationGroup %{GLOBAL}
        WSGIScriptReloading On
        Order deny,allow
        Allow from all
    </Directory>

    ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
</VirtualHost>
```

I've searched around for a while trying to figure this out but I'm stumped.  I'm also fairly new to web design, so it could be something silly.  Thanks in advance.

Comment: your code doesn't match with the error, are you sure you copied everything right in the question? the error claims "cannot import name application" but in your code you have "from site import app"

Comment: The line of code in the traceback does not match what's in the file. Double check that you've saved the files properly, and that they're saved in the right place.

Comment: Also rename site.py to some other name, as it is very likely that it conflicts with site.py from Python's standard library.

Comment: The error was supposed to say app rather than application - that was the result of an old attempted fix and I copied the wrong line.  The error was indeed due to naming it site.py.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found the answer - as Audrius said in the comments, it was a conflict because I named the file site.py.  I changed it to mysite.py everywhere necessary and added the following to mysite.wsgi (formerly site.wsgi):

```
import sys
sys.path.insert(0, '/home/www/mysite.wsgi')
```